# Removing child node from selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, lxml

I'm creating a project in scrapy whereby I scrape (obviously!) particular data from a webpage.

```
items = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productTiles cf"]/ul').extract()
     for item in items:
            price = sel.xpath('//ul/li[@class="productPrice"]/span/span[@class="salePrice"]').extract()
            print price
```

This will product the following result:

```
u'<span class="salePrice">$20.43\xa0<span class="reducedFrom">$40.95</span></span>',     
u'<span class="salePrice">$20.93\xa0<span class="reducedFrom">$40.95</span></span>
```

What I need to get is just the salePrice, e.g. 20.43 and 20.93 respectively, while ignoring the rest of the other tag and the rest of the data. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is as follows:

```
//ul/li[@class="productPrice"]/span/span[@class="salePrice"]//text()
```

It'll grab just the text of the correct element I'm looking for, like so:

```
u'$20.43\xa0', u'$20.93\xa0'
```

Now I can just parse it to remove the unnecessary rubbish at the end, and I'm set. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

`span[@class="salePrice"]` returns `span` with its children.

This should get only the text of the top `span`:

```
sel.xpath('//ul/li[@class="productPrice"]/span/span[@class="salePrice"]/text()').extract()[0]
```